React and Spline displaying scene in different screen view
I'm building a website using React+Spline 3D and I'm having problems in displaying my Spline Scene in different screen size (mobile, tablet, etc). I can use Spline's Screen Resize from events but I will have to trigger it to show a state screen view of my spline scene. If I manually resize my browser, it will work, but if I toggle the window size, refresh my page, or view automatically on table or mobile view, it will only display the Current or Base State of my spline scene.  What would be the best approach when displaying a responsive Spline scene? Here my Spline Scene
